# Coordinates for a neighborhood of a totally real submanifold

Tags: complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, almost-complex

**Motivation:** I'm interested in which submanifolds of (half dimension) a complex manifold can be expressed locally in coordinates as the real part of the complex coordinates, and was wondering if the name "totally real" had any connection to this.

**Definition:** Let $M$ be a $2n$-dimensional real manifold with an almost complex structure $J$. A submanifold $L \subset M$ is called **totally real** if it is of half the dimension of $M$ and $T_q L \cap J T_q L= \{0\}$ for $q$ in $L$.

**Question:** I have two questions, but one is a generalization of the other.

Question 1: If $M$ is actually a complex manifold (i.e., $J$ is integrable) and $L \subset M$ is a totally real submanifold, does this imply that there exists holomorphic coordinates $(z^k= x^k + iy^k)$ on some neighborhood $U$ in $M$ such that $U \cap L = \{y^k =0\}$?

Question 2: Same as Question 1, but where $M=T^*L$ and $L$ is viewed as zero section, and it is assumed that $T^*M$ is complex manifold.

Comment: Let $M=\mathbb{C}$. If $L \subset \mathbb{C}$ is locally defined by $\{y=0\}$, then $L$ is the zero of an harmonic function. I think there are curves in $\mathbb{C}$ which are not locally the zero of an harmonic function, however I don't have any reference.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the 2nd question (I think, there are some assumptions missing here). Formally speaking the answer to Question 1 is negative since the existence of such a holomorphic change of variables implies that $L$ is a real-analytic submanifold (and not every totally real submanifold is real-analytic as you can see already in the case of real curves in ${\mathbb C}$). However, if you assume, additionally, that $L$ is real-analytic, then the answer is positive, see Lemma in my answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380169/a-normal-form-of-local-anti-holomorphic-involutions-of-mathbb-c2/380305#380305) Mathoverflow question.